# Trying to access dynamic array of Public Game Objects from the inspector

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an array of Public Game Objects variable from the inspector. I am having an issue understanding how I should be dealing with using the variable "i" as the index for the array. I get an error that says value expected, but I am not sure if I should be adding the "i" variable to my index, for example: `ThingToKill[i].SetActive(true);`.
The only way I can get this to work is to hard code in the number if Game Objects I want, so for instance this `ThingToKill[1].SetActive(true);` will allow me to affect 2 game objects.

Here is my code:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class publicarray : MonoBehaviour
   {



public GameObject[] ThingToKill;
public float startAfterThisManySeconds;
public float endafterThisManySeconds;


void Start()
{
    ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false);
    StartCoroutine("turnOn");
    StartCoroutine("turnOff");

    for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(ThingToKill[i].name);
    }
}



void Update()
{

}

IEnumerator turnOn()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startAfterThisManySeconds);
    StartCoroutine("on");
    Debug.Log("on");


}

IEnumerator turnOff()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(endafterThisManySeconds + startAfterThisManySeconds);
    StartCoroutine("off");
    Debug.Log("off");


}
IEnumerator on()
{

    ThingToKill[].SetActive(true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.000001f);



}
IEnumerator off()
{
    ThingToKill[].SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.000001f);
}
}
```

*EDIT* This was the solution that worked:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class publicarray : MonoBehaviour
{



    public GameObject[] ThingToKill;
    public float startAfterThisManySeconds;
    public float endafterThisManySeconds;


    void Start()
    {

       for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(ThingToKill[i].name);
            ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine("turnOn");
            StartCoroutine("turnOff");
        }
    }



    void Update()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator turnOn()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(startAfterThisManySeconds);
        StartCoroutine("on");
        Debug.Log("on");


    }

    IEnumerator turnOff()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(endafterThisManySeconds + startAfterThisManySeconds);
        StartCoroutine("off");
        Debug.Log("off");


    }
    IEnumerator on()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
        {
            ThingToKill[i].SetActive(true);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.000001f);

            }
        }

    IEnumerator off()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
        {

            ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.000001f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very cool, I didn't realize you could use dynamic arrays via the inspector, I will have to play with that.  Do more fields for the array automatically get added in the inspector to accommodate more objects as you add them, or do you have a field in the inspector that specifies how big you want the array to be?

Comment: @StephenDocy  -  More fields do get automatically created, it is incredibly convenient. If you use this script you will see that you can change a public int called "Size" which will create as many fields as you specify.

Answer (score 0):

Take

```
ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false);
StartCoroutine("turnOn");
StartCoroutine("turnOff");
```

and place it inside the `for-loop`. It's throwing an error because `i` is local to the loop, which means that outside of it it's undefined. Placing it in the loop will resolve the problem:

```
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ThingToKill.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(ThingToKill[i].name);
        ThingToKill[i].SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine("turnOn");
        StartCoroutine("turnOff");
    }
}
```